# Prove that exist $f_1$ and $f_2$ such that $f=f_1+f_2$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, power-series, laurent-series

Suppose $f$ is analytic  on the ring $D(0,1;2)$ Through the Laurent series of $f$ prove that there exist $f_1$ analytic on $D(0;2)$ and $f_2$ analytic on the ring $D(0;1,+\infty)$ such that $f=f_1+f_2$ on the initial ring $D(0,1;2)$ .

I dont know even how to start .I know that having the laurent series  the function will look like 2 polynomials one with negative powers of $z$ kai one with positive powers of $z$(taylor expansion) those 2 polynomials might do the work since they are analytic inside the radius of convergence but i have no idea if its the correct way to go  .And i dont have any more info. and i dont know how to write those things down.

Comment: It is the correct way to go :)

Comment: @Elad can you help me on writing it down?

Comment: Split the Laurent series into the part with $n \geqslant 0$ and the part with $n < 0$. Where does each part of the series converge?

Comment: @DanielFischer i imagine that for the terms $n$ positive it converges inside  the circle  radius 2 and for the negative  converge outside the circle  of radious 1. still i dont know how to prove it  and it is just speculations

Comment: i need to formal write it down not just say it. is there a theorem or something that i can recall or use it ? that will grant me the existance and the analyciti of those 2 functions?

Comment: You imagine right. What do you know about the region of convergence of a power series?

Comment: @DanielFischer i just know that if i can find the coeficients of the series then i know it exists. and i can calculate the radius by taking a formula 1/limitroot .

Comment: Regardless of the specifics, if a power series converges anywhere, what shape has the region of convergence?

Comment: @DanielFischer I guess a circle .or a circle with a whole?

Comment: A disk. (Possibly the entire plane). The region of convergence of a power series has no holes. So from the fact that the series for $f_1$ converges at $z_0$, you can deduce that it converges at least on the disk $\{ z : \lvert z\rvert < \lvert z_0\rvert\}$. Since it converges for all $z_0$ with $1 < \lvert z_0\rvert < 2$, it follows that it converges at least on the disk $\{ z : \lvert z\rvert < 2\}$. The series for $f_2$ is not a power series, but a simple substitution converts it into one. That shows that this series converges for $\lvert z\rvert > 1$.

Comment: ooooooooh i got it .So i use the fact that the region of a power series is alway a disk for all z .Where can i see this result about the disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right path.

If $f$ is analytic on the ring $D(0;1,2)$, there exists a Laurent series expansion by the Laurent's theorem:
$$f(z)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}a_nz^n$$
for some $a_n\in \mathbb{C}$.

Let $f_1$ and $f_2$ be the following function:
$$f_1(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$$
$$f_2(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{-n}z^{-n}$$

Then $f=f_1+f_2$ and $f_1$ is analytic on the disc $|z|<2$. The function $f$ is analytic for $1<|z|<2$, so the radius of convergence of the power series $f_1$ is greater or equal to $2$, otherwise the function $f$ would not be defined in the ring. One of the properties of the radius of convergence is that a power series converges if $|z|<\rho_1$, where $\rho_1$ is the radius of convergence of the power series. This proves the convergence on the disk $D(0;2)$ of the power series $f_1$.

For $f_2$, substitute $w=z^{-1}$. The power series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{-n}w^{n}$$
have a radius of convergence greater or equal to $1$, otherwise the function $f$ would not be analytic on the ring. For the same reason as the construction of $f_1$, the power series is convergent if $|w|<1$ (or $|z|>1$).

Comment: why $f1$ is analytic on the disc?You say that f1 is analytic on the disc and then  that converges for  >=2. and then <2?

Comment: A power series is always analytic on its disc of convergence. This is usually a theorem seen in the beginning of a complex analysis class.

Comment: could i have swaped the radiuses of the functions?since the first argument you made for f1 can be used for f2?

Comment: No, you can put a lower bound on each radius of convergence by asking yourself the question: is the function $f$ analytic on the ring if the radius of convergence of the power series of $f_1$ is less than...? (and the same thing for $f_2$).

Comment: one last thing i get why f1 must be analytic on a radius at least 2 now for the second one f2 you say must be analytic on a radius at least 1  why? our initial f is not analytic on $D(0;1)$

Comment: If the radius of convergence $\rho$ was less than one, then for every $w$ such that $\rho<|w|<1$, the power series would diverge. This implies that if we pick $z$ such that $1<|z|<\frac{1}{\rho}$, then the series of $f_2$ would diverge also. The function $f=f_1+f_2$ could not be analytic on the ring $1<|z|<\frac{1}{\rho}$, which is a subset of the ring $D(0;1,2)$.